# regular expression for java string match "number(number)."

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

What I am saying is, I am trying to make a method to filter out an array of strings base on regular expression , but I cannot achieve this.
E.g . I have an array

```
String[] items = ["6652(1).png", "7876(2).png", "7890-(1).jpg", "6543(1).JPG", "12249(3)-.PNG"]

public ArrayList<String> filterByRegularExpress(String[] items) {
    ArrayList<String> filteredStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String item: items) {
        if(item.contains("regularexpression")){ // it is in here, i need to do some regular express for number(number).
            filteredStrings.add(item);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(filteredStrings);
}
```

so the result will be `"6652(1).png" , "7876(2).png" , "6543(1).JPG"`  only

How do I write such regular expression?
Thanks for help advance.

Comment: Well maybe check one of the various online tutorial on regular expressions and then check your created expression with one of the various online regEx tools available.

Comment: Why you _can't achieve this_?

Comment: By the way..contains compares the string. So if a substring is found, inside of the string to call contains on. If you want to see if a regular expressions "matches", than use string.matches(regEx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the body of your method:

```
ArrayList<String> filteredStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\A\\d+\\(\\d+\\)\\..+\\z");
for(String item: items) {
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(item);
    if(matcher.matches()){ // it is in here, i need to do some regular express for number(number).
        filteredStrings.add(item);
    }
}
System.out.print(filteredStrings);
```

This will match a String based on the start of the input (`\\A`), followed by any number of digits (at least one, though, `\\d+`), followed by a literal opening parenthesis which is escaped because it has a special meaning in a Regex (`\\(`), then any number of digits between the brackets (if that can only be one digit in your scenario, simply remove the `+`), then the closing bracket, again escaped like the opening one, then a literal ., escaped because of the special meaning of . in a Regex (`\\.`), then we use that special meaning of ., which means "any character", and we say there can be any number of any character here (`.+`), followed by the ending of the String (`\\z`). So to summarize, in a more human-readable way, this matches `number(number).anything`. In your example, I tested it and got the correct output `[6652(1).png, 7876(2).png, 6543(1).JPG]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with pattern

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("There are more than -2 and less than 12 numbers here");
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

As per Java regular expressions, the  + means "one or more times" and \d means "a digit".

Note: the "double backslash" is an escape sequence to get a single backslash - therefore, \d in a java String gives you the actual result: \d

Comment: I like the approach of using Pattern and matcher, instead of string.matches(), to not create a pattern in every for() iteration. Further, there is no need for the find and group. if m.matches == true, then you can add the string to the result list.